# Clarification for web.config security to deny IP Address

Tags: asp.net, web-config

Could someone please help me understand the system.webServer config section below. Basically,

1. What does subnet mask do?
2. What happens if we don't specify subnet mask?
3. How to add range of IP Addresses?

> add allowed=”true” ipAddress=”192.168.100.1” subnetMask=”255.255.0.0

?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj154098.aspx

How do I apply some IP Address and block some IP address?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A **subnet mask** separates the IP address into the network and host addresses.

> What does subnet mask do?

`subnetMask` is used to block/allow range of IP address in network:

eg: `<add ipAddress="83.116.119.0" subnetMask="255.255.255.0"/>`

is used to block network `83.116.119.0` to `83.116.119.255` IPs.

> What happens if we don't specify subnet mask?

If you don't specify subnet mask, eg.: `<add ipAddress="83.116.19.53"/>`  it will block only one IP.

> How to add range of IP Addresses?

You can see the range of example to answer your question:

```
<add ipAddress="1.2.3.0" subnetMask="255.255.255.0"/>     <!--blocks network 1.2.3.0 to 1.2.3.255-->                
<add ipAddress="1.2.0.0" subnetMask="255.255.0.0"/>     <!--blocks network 1.2.0.0 to 1.2.255.255-->                
<add ipAddress="1.0.0.0" subnetMask="255.0.0.0"/>     <!--blocks network 1.0.0.0 to 1.255.255.255-->
```

To block all IPs, except those listed:

```
<ipSecurity allowUnlisted="true">
```

Comment: Thanks heaps, you are legend.